# Error compiling latex

Tags: errors

I need help, I am very desperate. I was advancing in my thesis as I do daily, and suddenly an error appeared which I do not know how to fix it although it seems simple:

```
l.25 \ begin {document}
I suspect you have forgotten a `} ', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `` E 'or `` X' now and fix your file
```

The latex file is arranged in folders, so I uploaded it to overleaf at this link: https://es.overleaf.com/project/614bfaadd43c8785043b986a. Currently I cannot compile the latex file because of the error mentioned above. I really need help, it's maddening when I can't fix a mistake like that in a thesis. I don't know if I pressed or deleted a character an error. I know the error is `} ', but I can't find it. I would appreciate if you can help me because I have little left to finish my thesis and present it. Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Currently I cannot compile the latex file because of the error mentioned above.

Comment: you have not shown the error message just the following help text

Comment: you could show a document that produces the error in this question (the error is in the first 25 lines(. It is best not to use external links, especially that overleaf link which is to a private project that we can not see